# Trying to apply CONCATENATE via ARRAYFORMULA on Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the following formula that I would like to apply to a column via ARRAYFORMULA. Due to the fact that new rows are added via GOOGLE FORMS I cannot COPY + PASTE because each new FORM entry deletes all columns to the right.

```js
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"", CONCATENATE(E3," : [",G3,"] : ",H3," ( ",text(C3,"HH:MM")," - ",text(D3,"HH:MM")," )"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(E3:E100&" : ["&G3:G100&"] : "&H3:H100&" ( "&text(C3:C100,"HH:MM")*(A2:A100<>""))
```

which might be easier to follow as:

```
=ArrayFormula(  
E3:E100  
&  
" : ["  
&  
G3:G100  
&  
"] : "  
&  
H3:H100  
&  
" ( "  
&  
text(C3:C100,"HH:MM")  
*(A2:A100<>""))
```